# Installing CUB in nvidia nsight

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight, cub

I want to use CUB with NVIDIA Nsight. I looked for tutorials on the internet for doing that, but I didn't find anything, even in the official pages pf CUB.

What do I need to do in order to use CUB in code I write using NVIDIA Nsight?

Comment: CUB is a template library. You don't have to do anything except include it in your code and provide the compiler with the search path where the CUB files can be found. What is your question here?

Comment: Telling us what you want isn't the same thing as asking a question. I'll repeat, what is your question?

Comment: I want to use it with nsight I added  the path of the library to my project like this : right click on the project -> C/C++ General ->Paths and Symbols : after that I add the path of cub  in the tabs : includes,Libraries, library paths  like this : /home/sara/cub-1.6.4  but it dosen't work  @talonmes

Comment: @talonmies: Edited OP's question. Sara, please note that we expect questions to actually have the grammatical form of a questions rather than telling us what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do any installation since the CUB library is implemented as  C++ headers check it in the section number 6 in this page [here](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html). The only thing you need to is to add the path of the library to the includes of the projects as follow:
right click on your project go to properties, after that go to C/C++ general then click on Paths and symbols. in the **Includes** tab  ( the first tab)  you add the path of your library that's all.